# Running node inspector with protractor tests

Tags: javascript, gulp, protractor

Is there any way I can run `node --inspect` with protractor tests triggered via gulp-protractor?

**Edit:** this is how the protractor tests are run:

```
gulp.src(global.buildConfig.src.specsJs)
    .pipe(gulpProtractor.protractor({
        configFile: configPath,
        args: cmdArgs,
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) {
        throw err;
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      // ...
    });
```

Best I can come up with so far: bypass gulp.

```
node ./node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js ./test/browser/.protractorConfig.js --inspect
```

But I run into pathing issues with relative `require` imports in my tests.

Comment: I am sure you've tried it. What if you would add `--inspector` to the `cmdArgs` array?

Comment: IIUC, doing that passes that argument to protractor, which ignores it. It needs to be passed to the invocation of node.exe

Comment: Yeah, makes perfect sense, sorry for the dumb idea.